# NullPointerException Android Java

Tags: java, android, nullpointerexception, cursor

I'm receiving a nullPointerException error, during one of methods and I can't seem to work out why one of my variables(csID) is becoming null.

here is the method:

```
public String getSubjectBasedOnHID(int hID) {
    String selectQuerySubjectForHomework = "SELECT sID FROM homework WHERE hID = '"
            + hID + "';";
    HashMap<String, String> sIDD = new HashMap<String, String>();

    SQLiteDatabase database = this.getReadableDatabase();
        Cursor cursorGetsID = database.rawQuery(selectQuerySubjectForHomework,
            null);

    if (cursorGetsID.moveToFirst()) {
        HashMap<String, String> temp = new HashMap<String, String>();
        temp.put("sID", cursorGetsID.getString(0));

        sIDD = temp;
    }
     String csID = sIDD.get("sID").toString();




    String Subject = csID;
    return Subject;
};
```

csID becomes null (I think), which causes the program to crash, any help would be greatly Appreciated!

logCat:

```
    01-07 18:58:45.854: E/AndroidRuntime(2630): Caused by: java.lang.NullPointerException
01-07 18:58:45.854: E/AndroidRuntime(2630):     at com.compfour.homework.dataBaseTools2.getSubjectBasedOnHID(dataBaseTools2.java:284)
```

Thank you, in advance.

Comment: Put a System.out.print in the if statement to see if it is executing

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Try this code :

```
temp.put("sID", cursorGetsID.getString(cursorGetsID.getColumnIndexOrThrow("hID")));

// hID is your colunm name in SQLite data table, you can change it to another
```

Answer (score 1):

If there are no records returned and your `Cursor` is empty, `sIDD.get("sID")` will return null.

You should handle that in your code:

```
if (sIDD.containsKey("sID"))
    return sIDD.get("sID").toString();
else
    return null; // or empty string or anything suitable in this case
```

Comment: Using the debug I can see that sIDD and temp are always null. This is where my real problem lays, i can seem to work out why they are null.